# Is this alias any useful?

Tags: linux, shell, alias, tcsh

I am going through and old `.cshrc` file and it contains the following alias:

```
alias pwd 'echo $cwd'
```

How is that useful?

I used to think that this is how `pwd` might have been implemented. But looks like thats not the case (because then this alias is meaningless).

Comment: Meta: I believe you should have added the word "pwd" to the question's title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.sunmanagers.org/archives/1996/0273.html

This mailing list archive shows the subtle differences between the two that existed in 1996. Not sure if they still exist now, but since you mentioned an *old* file...

Basically, `cwd` only prints out where `csh` thinks it is, instead of the absolute path that `pwd` will figure out.

To quote Scott Williamson in that thread:

> Yes, the difference is that $cwd will
>   give you the path that the shell  took
>   to get to that directory because it
>   doesn't know any better. pwd  will
>   give the real physical directory
>   because it starts at the current 
>   directory and works back up the
>   hierarchy.  So symbolic links and
>   mounting or re-mounting directories
>   will confuse  $cwd.

Comment: The Mac OS version of `pwd` has a `-L` switch that displays the current working directory without resolving symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

At least under Mac OS, there is a program called `pwd` in /bin, and it works with `tcsh` no problem. It's probably there under Linux too.

I suggest you unalias `pwd` and check with `which pwd` if you have a replacement.